How do I created image out of an exited container using crictl?
We hosted our application pods on K8S v1.29 and uses crictl
One of our application pod exited and we are unable to connect to pod and debug
I would be able to create a new docker image out of an exited container and would be able to debug it as mentioned in the URL here
Likewise, how can I create an image out of an exited container using crictl and debug it
